# How to disable PHPMailer Mail Delivery Failed message

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've got a PHPMailer set up to send users an E-Mail after submitting a form, which works perfectly fine. *But* once in a while users of our service insert a wrong e-mail-address, or just make a typo. As a result, I'm getting a "Mail Deilivery System" mail about how my PHPMailer was unable to reach the mistyped address.

Is there a way to disable these kind of messages in PHPMailer?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not getting these _from_ PHPMailer in the first place. You get them from either the mail server you handed your mail over to for delivery (in cases like when the target host doesn’t exist), or from the receiving system (like when it doesn’t know the mail account.)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I added a filter in my mail client to automatically move these mails to another folder. It's also a solution.